# Select records with with two like statements

Tags: sqlite, sql-like

This query in `sqlite`:

```
SELECT * from INVENTORY WHERE product like '250541%'
```

returns some records. Also the following returns some records:

```
SELECT * from INVENTORY WHERE product like '250341%'
```

However if I want to select both of them like:

```
SELECT * from INVENTORY WHERE product like '250541%' and product like '250341%'
```

I don't get any result. What am I type wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is perfectly fine,Its up to you which condition you want to use AND or OR,if you want to fetch the records starting with product "250541" and "250341" then you have to use OR condition.Because both condition does not meet with AND condition that's why you are not getting any record.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your data, but if you want both results you should use `OR` instead of `AND` between the `LIKE` statements